# The download event keeps firing every time I click another button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I've added `router.push(`${previewUrl}`)` to the Button component inside the PayDetail children. It does what it needs to do but whenever I click a button (different component) from another children inside the same parent the `router.push(`${previewUrl}`)` keeps firing...

PayDetails.tsx (children)

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import Button from '@/app/components/Button'
import { useEffect } from "react";

interface PayDetailsProps {
  bookId: number
  title: string
  intro: string
  price: number
  previewUrl: string
}

const PayDetails: React.FC<PayDetailsProps> = ({
  bookId,
  title,
  intro,
  price,
  previewUrl,
}) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <div className="w-full tablet:max-w-[384px] flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-[24px] tablet:p-[24px] tablet:border-[1px] tablet:border-border-main rounded-[10px] my-[40px] tablet:my-[0px]">
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-[24px]">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start justify-start gap-[8px]">
          <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start justify-start gap-[6px]">
            <p className="text-[22px] leading-[130%] font-medium">{title}</p>
          </div>
          <p className="text-[16px] leading-[150%] text-main-gray">{intro}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full flex items-center justify-between">
          <div className="flex items-start justify-center text-[24px] font-semibold">
            <p>{`${price.toLocaleString()}원`}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3">
        <div className="flex w-full h-[42px]">
          <Button
            label="preview"
            onClick={() => router.push(`${previewUrl}`)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex w-full h-[42px]">
          <Button
            label="buy"
            onClick={() => {
              console.log('not fill')
            }}
            fill
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PayDetails
```

page.tsx (parent)

```
import { use } from 'react'

import Container from '@/app/components/Container'
import Thumbnail from '@/app/books/[id]/Thumbnail'
import DescriptionMenu from '@/app/books/[id]/DescriptionMenu'
import BookDescription from '@/app/books/[id]/BookDescription'
import TableOfContents from '@/app/books/[id]/TableOfContents'
import Author from '@/app/books/[id]/Author'
import PayDetails from '@/app/books/[id]/PayDetails'

import { fetchBook } from '@/app/libs/network'

export default function productPage({
  params: { id },
}: {
  params: { id: number }
}) {
  const bookData = use(fetchBook(id))

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <div className="w-full flex items-start justify-start gap-[40px]">
          <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start justify-start gap-[40px]">
            <Thumbnail src={bookData.thumbnailUrl} title={bookData.title} />
            <div className="flex tablet:hidden w-full">
              <PayDetails
                bookId={id}
                title={bookData.title}
                intro={bookData.intro}
                price={bookData.price}
                previewUrl={bookData.previewUrl}
              />
            </div>
            <DescriptionMenu />
            <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-[80px]">
              <BookDescription
                  descriptionUrl={bookData.descriptionUrl}
                  title={bookData.title}
              />
              <TableOfContents />
              <Author
                src={bookData.author.thumbnailUrl}
                name={bookData.author.name}
                description={bookData.author.description}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="hidden tablet:flex w-full max-w-[384px]">
            <PayDetails
              bookId={id}
              title={bookData.title}
              intro={bookData.intro}
              price={bookData.price}
              previewUrl={bookData.previewUrl}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

BookDescription.tsx (other children)

```
"use client"
import Title from '../../components/DescriptionTitle'
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

interface BookDescriptionProps {
    descriptionUrl: string
    title: string
}

const BookDescription: React.FC<BookDescriptionProps> = ({ descriptionUrl, title }) => {

    const [openDesc, setOpenDesc] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div id="book-description" className="w-full flex flex-col items-start justify-start gap-[60px]">
      <Title title="Intro" />
        <div className={openDesc === 0
            ? "w-full h-[500px] flex items-start justify-center overflow-hidden relative"
            : "w-full h-auto pb-[180px] flex items-start justify-center overflow-hidden relative"
        }>
            <Image src={descriptionUrl} alt={title} width="750" height="1000" className="h-auto"/>
            <div className="w-full h-[180px] bg-gradient-to-t from-background to-background/[0] absolute bottom-0 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <button
                    className="w-full max-w-[420px] h-[44px] rounded-[4px] bg-secondary-red text-main-white font-medium"
                    onClick={() => openDesc === 0
                        ? setOpenDesc(1)
                        : setOpenDesc(0)
                }
                >
                    {openDesc === 0
                    ? "See more"
                    : "See less"
                    }
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BookDescription
```

I just want the router.push to fire under the PayDetails children and not anywhere else..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.